# You do not have privileges to manipulate with the users!

Tags: mariadb, phpmyadmin

Error message:

```
You do not have privileges to manipulate with the users!
```

Appears in PhpMyAdmin using Mariadb 10.3.7 on MacOs High Sierra installation from Homebrew

I'm logged in as root
installed and rebooted with multiple server options: Mysql 5.7, Mysql 8.0
Mariadb 10.2 and 10.3.7.

I've tried everything from granting tables, flushing the permissions. 
I need to be able to edit users from the PhpMyAdmin page and its not allowing me even though I have root access (with password set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to comments in [this Github issue report](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14433) for phpMyAdmin, you probably need to set this option:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['DisableIS'] = true;
```

in `config.inc.php`. Though it sounds like this is a workaround for a bug, so may be fixed in later releases or not an issue in earlier releases.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this recalcitrant problem in Ubuntu after upgrading MySQL despite 'uninstalling' it. The problem is that the **mysql** schema is retained at */var/lib/mysql* and the upgrade changes the number of columns in the **user** table. It seems that as a safety measure, the installer alters the permissions on the phpMyAdmin administrator (and even root). If this is your problem (examine the user table in the mysql schema in the mysql command-line console) then fix each flag along the lines of:

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv = 'Y' WHERE user = 'phpmyadmin' AND host =
> 'localhost';

You'll need to do this for every affected privilege.

Comment: I don't think it's such a good idea to manipulate system tables directly. Wouldn't issuing the corresponding `GRANT` statements be safer?

Comment: Uhh, the whole point was that the GRANT statement wasn't working because of the 'conservative corruption' of the table! A bit of a pickle, until you work out that the UPDATE still works :) I describe the issues further in a post on Medium: https://dr-jo.medium.com/the-fourth-circle-a2831bbdf769

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by changing my control user to 'root' and then logging in with phpMyAdmin as 'root'. That seems overly simplistic, but it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  However I would rather not have a control user as root if I can help it since it creates a huge security hole.

Answer (score -2):

See fix and patches here at phpmyadmin:

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14433#issuecomment-544249375

Answer (score -2):

simply use chrome browser and you won't face this problem.

Open your phpmyadmin in chrome and you are good to go!!

You will have this problem in internet explorer but not in chrome.

Comment: if you think I use IE you have to be daft